# SQLite3 in python, How to accept variable amount of input

Tags: python, database, sqlite

So i am making a Recipes table in sqlite3.

but each recipe wont have the same amount of ingredients
for example:

recipe:
coke uses only 1 bottle

but
recipe:
coffee uses milk and coffee beans

here is the current code i have to insert the data into the table

```
def add_to_recipes(database):
    try:
        sq = sqlite3.connect(database)
        cursor = sq.cursor()

        insert_query = f"""INSERT INTO recipes (
                        recipes,
                        i_1,
                        a_1,
                        i_2,
                        a_2
                        ) VALUES (?,?,?,?);"""

        data_to_add = (input('Name of Recipe '),
                        input('name of ingredient 1'),
                        float(input('Amount of ingredient used ')),
                        input('Name of ingredient 2'),
                        float(input('Amount of ingredient used ')))
        
        cursor.execute(insert_query, data_to_add)
        sq.commit()
        cursor.close()
    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print(error)
    finally:
        if sq:
            sq.close()
```

i_1 is ingredient 1
a_1 is the amount used for ingredient 1

my real table will accept a max of 10 ingredients and 10 amounts

but if a user doesnt need to enter that many ingredients then their input would be none

the problem im having is that an empty input is a the string
''

so my float(input) gives a conversion error

my question is:
am i doing this the right way or should i design a while loop

Comment: I'd suggest have a look into using an ORM such as SQLAlchemy, it requires a bit more prior setup before using but stuff like this becomes incredibly easy.

Comment: Trying to use a variable number of *columns* is usually the sign of a poor design. Relational databases are better suited when you have a variable number of *rows*. For example you could have a `Recipe` table and an `Ingredient` table (with a foreign key referencing the recipe). Or even an `Ingredient` table (without foreign key) and a `Recipe_Ingredient` join table having two foreign keys (and the amount)

Comment: I think that [this](https://launchschool.com/books/sql/read/table_relationships#databasedesign) is a good start (the part about identifying entities and relations)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so shortly after posting this i have come up with the following solution

```
insert_query = f"""INSERT INTO recipes (
                        recipes,
                        i_1,
                        a_1,
                        i_2,
                        a_2
                        ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);"""

        data_to_add = [input('Name of Recipe ')]
        choice = 'yes'
        while choice == 'yes':
            i = input('ingredient ')
            a = float(input('amount '))
            data_to_add.append(i)
            data_to_add.append(a)
            choice = input()

        while len(data_to_add) < 5:
            data_to_add.append(None)
            print(len(data_to_add))
```

by using 2 while loops i can accept how ever many inputs i need and then make the
remaining required inputs None to avoid any value to columns errors